# Using java super and exends with lambda expressions

Tags: java, super, extends

I am fairly new to Java, currently learning about lambda expressions.
so I wanted to use generic with the Consumer function to make it accept any type of parameter passed to it and just print it out

The consumer accepts the first generic as the type that must be passed to it as the first param
I specified it to be (? extends Object) (I thinks it means anything that extends object which means anything in java that is not primitive) so it should accept any parameter passed to it including the list I am creating, but no error happens.

```
Supplier<List<String>> listSupplier = () -> new ArrayList<>();
Supplier<List<String>> listSupplierTwo = ArrayList::new;

Consumer<? super Object> logger = (a) -> System.out.println(a);
Consumer<? extends Object> loggerTwo = System.out::println;

var result = listSupplier.get();
var resultTwo = listSupplierTwo.get();

logger.accept("fooooo"); // compiles
logger.accept(result); // compiles
        
loggerTwo.accept(resultTwo); // error
loggerTwo.accept("fooooo"); // error
```

when replacing the extends with super(? super Object)(I think it means anything that is super class of Object class which is nothing as super dosent extend anything) it accepts any param and everything works

I searched a lot maybe I have incorrect understanding of how extends and super works may be I am incorrectly using the wildcard ? should I only use it with only collections ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned all usage of chatgpt is banned here.

Comment: @tgdavies 
well it answered half of the question which is why this function works

Consumer<? super Object> logger = (a) -> System.out.println(a);

but didnt answer why this fails -->

Consumer<? extends Object> loggerTwo = System.out::println;

still anything(not primitive) in java extends Object so this function should accept anything

Comment: wrong `? extends Object` means a specific type that extends Object. `Object` alone would mean anything that extends Object, that is, an instance of Object or any direct or indirect subclass  of Object - so `Consumer<? extends Object>` could be a `Consumer<Object>`, or a `Consumer<Integer>`,  or a `Consumer<Exception>`, or ... and obviously a `Consumer<Integer>` or `Consumer<Exception>`  cannot *accept* a `List<String>`

Comment: on the other side, a `Consumer<? super Object>` could be a `Consumer<Object>`  or a Consumer of any parent of Object (there is no, but that is not relevant); so `Consumer<? super Object>` will always be able to accept an instance of Object or of a subclass of Object. -- similar case: `Consumer<? super Number>` could be an instance of a `Consumer<Number>`, or even of `Consumer<Object>`; any of these will be able to accept a `Number` or subclass of it (`Integer`, `Double`, ...) || to accept any object, use `Consumer<Object>`, no `?` needed since any non-primitive type is a subclass of `Object`

Comment: @MohamedHossam `?` means "Do not know". So, in `Consumer<? extends Object>`, you should read that as: "A Consumer that can consume __I do not know__ - but, I do know, whatever it is, it is a subtype of Object (or Object itself)". Given that it is not known what it is, calling `consumer.accept(ANYTHING)` will fail. Because it might not be what that consumer consumes. a `Consumer<? extends Object>` is therefore completely useless. Other than calling `.accept()`, it has no purpose, and you can't call that with anything except the`null` literal as that is all types.

Comment: In contrast, read `Consumer<? super Object>` as "A Consumer that consumes __I do not know__; all I know is, it is either Object or a supertype of Object". Which, trivially, boils down to just Object, and indeed that is again completely useless; you would just write `Consumer<Object>` then. Also, `Consumer<? extends Object>` is the same as `Consumer<?>`. After all, "I do not know; all I know is, it extends Object or is Object" can be summarized as simply: "I do not know" - because _all_ things extend Object, that doesn't add any meaning at all.